# A function that checks the average of dict items

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a dictionary into a function that caculated the average, I believe my function is good but I'm having trouble with sending the dictionary

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}

def avg(dict):

    sum=0
    count=0
    for k,v in dict:
        sum = sum+v
        count +=1
    return(sum/count)


result = avg(**my_dict)

print(result)
```

The output should be 100 that goes into "result"

Comment: sum(my_dict.values()) / len(d)

Comment: The output should be 100, right? Or do you wish to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}
def dictavg(your_dict):
    return sum(your_dict.values())/len(your_dict)
print(dictavg(my_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your dictionary directly, not via the `**` dictionary unpacking operator. Do the unpacking *within your function* instead: iterating [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) gives key-value pairs, but here you can use [`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

Also, **never shadow built-ins**. So don't use `dict`, `sum`, etc as variable names.

This would work:

```
def avg(d):

    val_sum = 0
    count = 0
    for v in d.values():
        val_sum += v
        count += 1
    return(val_sum/count)

result = avg(my_dict)  # 100.0
```

You can also use the built-ins [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
result = sum(my_dict.values()) / len(my_dict.values())
```

Or use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from statistics import mean

result = mean(my_dict.values())  # 100
```

Comment: I wonder how to rewrite this if we were to pass as unpacking operator.

Comment: @YOLO, Unpacking doesn't help you solve your problem. So I advise you don't do it.

Comment: @jpg actually it is solvable with unpacking, just very superfluous. `f = lambda **kwargs: sum(kwargs.values())/len(kwargs)` then `f(**my_dict)`

Comment: @YOLO see my comment above

Comment: @DeepSpace, Yes, but that doesn't help. It's an extremely poor use of function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the asterisks and use `.items()` on the dict

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}

def avg(dict):

    sum=0
    count=0
    for k,v in dict.items():
        sum = sum+v
        count +=1
    return(sum/count)


result = avg(my_dict)

print(result)
```

Comment: `k` is not being used. You can just sum the values with `sum(dict.values())`.

Comment: Oh yeah, true.. I only changed the bits it failed on, didn't re-write it (or I would have also changed the poorly chosen variable names)

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
my_dict = {'first': 100, 'second': 0, 'third': 200}
avg = sum(my_dict.values()) / len(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the following statement with a dictionary:

```
for k, v in dict:
```

instead there is a way to receive a list of the keys or the values of the dictionary using the methods keys() or values() respectively. these methods return a list of the dictionary keys or the dictionary values and then you can iterate over them. Also there is a method which returns a list of tuples of key and value - items().

So any of these should work for you:

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}

def avg(dicti):

    total_sum=0
    count=0
    for key in dicti.keys():
        sum += dicti[key]
        count +=1
    return(sum/count)

result = avg(my_dict)

print(result)
```

or:

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}

def avg(dicti):

    total_sum=0
    count=0
    for value in dicti.values():
        sum += value
        count +=1
    return(sum/count)

result = avg(my_dict)

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont use keywords as variable names, such as `dict` or `sum`. You can send your whole dictionary, and iterate over the items:

```
my_dict = {"first": 100, "second": 0, "third": 200}

def avg(a_dict):
    total=0
    count=0
    for k,v in a_dict.items():
        total = total+v
        count +=1
    return(total/count)


result = avg(my_dict)

print(result)
```

Note that the avg is 100.